# Spring MVC parsing multipart content request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I`m going right on this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/
and implemented a multipart file upload controller.

However, stuck on getting this error:

```
type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

Here is my code for **controller**, just right from official tutorial:

```
    package com.springapp.mvc;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

    import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;

@Controller
public class FileUploadController {
        @RequestMapping(value="/api/items/upload_image", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                                                     @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
            if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                    BufferedOutputStream stream =
                            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name)));
                    stream.write(bytes);
                    stream.close();
                    return "You successfully uploaded " + name + "!";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
                }
            } else {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
            }
        }
}
```

And just for additional info, this is how i send **request from front-end** on angularjs. Request senging successfully:

```
    Upload.upload({
        url: '/api/items/upload_image',
        file: $file,
        name: $file.name,
        progress: function(e){}
    }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // file is uploaded successfully
        console.log(data);
    });
```

What i the problem can be?
All needed dependencies included.

Comment: I think you should check your web.xml for `<multipart-config>` - in tutorial this part should be created by Spring Boot. Second option - check that you uses Spring Servlet 3.0 component in your application.

Comment: Have you configured a `MultipartResolver` in your Spring XML config file? Like: `<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">`...

Comment: Have you configured a MultipartResolver in your Spring XML config file? - no, not. how do i configure it correctly? sorry, it's my first project on Spring MVC.

i tryed to do by spring boot from manual.. but it cause more and more errors...

Answer (score 0):

This was a **solution**:
include this dependencies in pom.xml

```
<!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Apache Commons IO -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Add** this bean in configuration:

```
class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />
</bean>
```